# Location sensor returns same location some times

Tags: android, geolocation

I am facing a weird issue on one of my devices,i have created a background service using google fused location API and its working perfect but in one of my devices some times it works perfectly but sometimes it keeps on returning the same lat long - and since i have added particular displacement so therefore location never updates.
the workaround I do is : to turn off and then on the location sensor and it starts sending location updates again.

Any idea why this might be happening ?

phone is Qmobile S4 - android 6.0

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out!
declare some final variables like this

```
private final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 3000;
private final int FAST_LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1500;
private final int MAX_WAIT_TIME = 5 * 1000;
private final float SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 10;
private final float TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
```

and assign them to your location request

```
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FAST_LOCATION_INTERVAL);
locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT);
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(MAX_WAIT_TIME);
```

connect your fused location provider if permission is available

```
 public void connect() {
    if (fusedLocationProviderClient != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
        //onLocationReceived(fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().getResult());
        isConnected = true;
    }
}
```

disconnect if you dont need location updates

```
public void disconnect() {
    if (fusedLocationProviderClient != null) {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        isConnected = false;
    }
}
```

override the locationCallback to get location result

```
locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            onLocationReceived(locationResult.getLastLocation());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
            super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
            //showToast("Location Available!");
        }
    };
```

This code works for me to update location frequently without any error.
Hope it helps you. Thank you!

Comment: could you tell me if this code would work for background location? I have a web plataform to track delivery around the city and Im getting problems with background tracking locations, I ask to LocationAvailability if I got location available with method LocationAvailability.isLocationAvailable() and it returns true, than I go for getLastLocation and the location almost everytime returns the same as I already got on my controller .. any advice?

Comment: @ArthurMelo Targeting android 12 you need to get background location permission from the user. Yes you can use the above code without disconnecting the fusedLocationProvider.